# How do I group by a certain field in reporting services?

Tags: reporting-services

I have the following table:

[image]

I want to create a report that groups by the "Date" field.

[image]

I do not know how to do it. Maybe I should use sub reports? Could you give me an idea?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a subreport, you need to add a group to your tablix. With the "details" row selected (by clicking on the left side) right-click to get a context menu and pick "Add group" - "Parent Group" and for the "Group By" pick the name of your date field.

[image]

[image]

This will cause all of the rows with the same date to be collected in groups, and you can add aggregate functions like average, sum, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was easier than I thought. A cordial greeting!

Comment: Hey @Raulus, glad it helped and thanks for letting me know, happy coding :-)